# Loading all text lines into different tables dynamically located in c

Tags: c

Command:

> the program reads the file and saves it in memory, treating each line as a subtitle (Note: to simplify the program, we can assume that we know the limit for the length of the line (say 1023 characters) and we know the limit for the number of lines (say 2048), but we expect that the lengths of individual lines can vary greatly, so we allocate the memory for each line dynamically during reading, writing the addresses of subsequent subtitles in the table)

I have a code that reads one line, but I don't know how to change it so that the program reads all the lines into different arrays and then reads the indicators into them into the next array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 1023
#define ROW 32

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *array;
    size_t csize = ROW;
    size_t cpos = 0;
    int ch;
    fp = fopen("plik.txt", "r");

    array = malloc(ROW);

    while((ch = fgetc(fp))!='\n'&& ch!='\r')
    {
        array[cpos++] = ch;
         if(cpos == csize)
            {
                csize += ROW;
                array = realloc(array, csize);
            }

    }
           array[cpos] = 0;

    fclose(fp);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have example how you can initialize dynamicaly two dimentional array of floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;

    printf("Enter x\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter y\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    float** matrix = (float**)malloc(x * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    {
        matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(y * sizeof(float));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            int value = rand()%10000;
            matrix[i][j] = (float)value / 100;
            printf("%.2f   ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Play a little bit with this code. You shouldn't have any problems to initialize every line with different length.